# trying to scrape information from a website that is not located inside a class but located in a script as a variable

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a website. The data I want is NOT contained in a div or class it is a push variable. I want to be able to search for "**average180.push([new Date(**" then i want to grab the immediately following characters. For example I want to grab the following characters that are contained within '' and assign that to a list (in this instance it is the date). I then want to grab the immediately following text contained within the commas (the price value) and assign that to a list. Once I have these two lists I can ziper them together and create my datatable

what I currently have

```
import sys
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/Raw_shark/viewitem?obj=383"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
information = soup.find_all("script")
print(information)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use re module for parsing the parameters:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
from pprint import pprint

url = "http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/Raw_shark/viewitem?obj=383"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")

return_value = []
for s in soup.find_all('script'):
    i = re.findall("average180.push\(\[new Date\('(.*?)'\).*?(\d+).*?(\d+)", s.text)
    for v in i:
        return_value.append(v)

pprint(return_value)
```

Output:

```
[('2018/01/13', '1584', '1389'),
 ('2018/01/14', '1530', '1396'),
 ('2018/01/15', '1512', '1402'),
 ('2018/01/16', '1501', '1408'),
 ('2018/01/17', '1489', '1414'),
 ('2018/01/18', '1483', '1420'),
 ('2018/01/19', '1487', '1427'),
 ('2018/01/20', '1511', '1435'),
 ('2018/01/21', '1516', '1443'),
 ('2018/01/22', '1517', '1449'),
 ('2018/01/23', '1529', '1456'),
 ('2018/01/24', '1527', '1463'),
 ('2018/01/25', '1524', '1470'),
 ('2018/01/26', '1498', '1477'),
 ('2018/01/27', '1491', '1484'),
...etc.
```